# MongoDB group by two field and format results

Tags: mongodb

I use mongodb $group to take the result.(group by hashtags and time))

I want to make the results like this:

```
{
    "_id" : { "hashtag" : "Google"  },
    "info" : [{ "date" : { "year" : 2015, "month" : 12, "day" : 24, "hour" : 16 }, "cnt" : 1 }, 
             { "date" : { "year" : 2015, "month" : 12, "day" : 25, "hour" : 15 }, "cnt" : 4 }, 
             { "date" : { "year" : 2015, "month" : 12, "day" : 25, "hour" : 17 }, "cnt" : 4}, ]
}
{
    "_id" : { "hashtag" : "Microsoft"  },
    "info" : [{ "date" : { "year" : 2015, "month" : 12, "day" : 25, "hour" : 11 }, "cnt" : 1 }, 
             { "date" : { "year" : 2015, "month" : 12, "day" : 24, "hour" : 17 }, "cnt" : 1 }, 
             { "date" : { "year" : 2015, "month" : 12, "day" : 21, "hour" : 18 }, "cnt" : 2 }, ]
}
```

here is my code:

```
var hashtags = ['Microsoft', 'Google'];
db.stream.aggregate([
    {
        '$match': {
             'hashtags': {"$in": hashtags},
            'time': {
                 $gt:new Date('2015-12-20'),
                 $lt:new Date('2015-12-27')
            }
        }
    },
    {'$unwind': '$hashtags'},
    {
        '$match': {
            'hashtags': {"$in": hashtags},
        }
    },
    {
        '$group': {
            '_id': {
                'hashtags': '$hashtags',
                'year': {'$year': '$time'},
                'month': {'$month': '$time'},
                'day': {'$dayOfMonth': '$time'},
                'hour': {'$hour': "$time"}
            },
            'cnt': {'$sum': 1},
        }
    },
    {
     '$project': {
       '_id':0,
       'hashtag': "$_id.hashtags",
       'info':{
         'date': {
            'year': "$_id.year",
            'month': "$_id.month",
            'day': "$_id.day",
            'hour': "$_id.hour",
          },
         'cnt': "$cnt"
       }
      }
   },
    {
        '$group': {
            '_id': {
                'hashtags': '$hashtag',
            },
            'info':{'$push':'$info'}
        }
    },
])
```

1. Firstly I use match to reduce the number of data
2. Note that hashtags is an array, (eg:['Microsoft','Surface'])so I use $unwind to take the hashtag only cantains Microsoft or Google.
3. My code is too ugly and slowly. Is there another way to solve it?

Comment: Your expected result is invalid. Can you be a little bit more clear on that?

Comment: @chridam Oh, I am sorry that I don't know where is invalid. Do you mean "_id" field?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `$project` operator.

```
var hashtags = ['Microsoft', 'Google'];
db.stream.aggregate([
    {
        '$match': {
             'hashtags': {"$in": hashtags},
            'time': {
                 $gt:new Date('2015-12-20'),
                 $lt:new Date('2015-12-27')
            }
        }
    },
    {'$unwind': '$hashtags'},
    {
        '$group': {
            '_id': {
                'hashtags': '$hashtags',
                'year': {'$year': '$time'},
                'month': {'$month': '$time'},
                'day': {'$dayOfMonth': '$time'},
                'hour': {'$hour': "$time"}
            },
            'cnt': {'$sum': 1},
        }
    },
   {
     '$project': {
       '_id': "$_id.hashtags",
       {
         '_id': {
            'year: "$_id.year",
            'month': "$_id.month",
            'day': "$_id.day",
            'hour': "$_id.hour",
          },
         'cnt': "$cnt"
       }
      }
   }
])
```

Comment: Have you tested this? This will definitely fail with the `Unexpected token {` error.

Comment: Nope, I did not tested it.

Comment: Thanks for use project suggesion. Now I change the code ? Can you give me some solution? Thanks~

Comment: You have to use $group twice I guess. I currently don't have MongoDB installed on my machine.  And note that it makes no sense to do a $match after $unwind.

Comment: @Rubysmith I use $unwind to take the hashtag only cantains microsoft or google. because hashtags is an array T^T

Comment: $unwind is fine but an another $match after $unwind is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Your objects are not proper JS objects.

You should keep it very simple by grouping them using mongo with the `hashtags`.

```
var data = db.stream.group(
   {
     key: { hashtags: 1},
     reduce: function ( curr, result ) { },
     initial: { }
   }
)
```

data:

```
    [{ "_id" : { "hashtags" : "Google", "year" : 2015, "month" : 12, "day" : 24, "hour" : 16 }, "cnt" : 1 },
{ "_id" : { "hashtags" : "Google", "year" : 2015, "month" : 12, "day" : 25, "hour" : 15 }, "cnt" : 4 }
,{ "_id" : { "hashtags" : "Google", "year" : 2015, "month" : 12, "day" : 25, "hour" : 17 }, "cnt" : 4 }
,{ "_id" : { "hashtags" : "Microsoft", "year" : 2015, "month" : 12, "day" : 25, "hour" : 11 }, "cnt" : 1 }
,{ "_id" : { "hashtags" : "Microsoft", "year" : 2015, "month" : 12, "day" : 24, "hour" : 17 }, "cnt" : 1 }
,{ "_id" : { "hashtags" : "Microsoft", "year" : 2015, "month" : 12, "day" : 21, "hour" : 18 }, "cnt" : 2 }]
```

and then use javascript to build your object:

```
var result = {
        "Microsoft": [],
    "Google": []
};
```

Map through the data to create your 2 properties object:

```
data.map(function (elem) {
        result[elem._id.hashtags].push(elem);
})
```

result:

```
{
    "Google": [
        { "_id" : { "year" : 2015, "month" : 12, "day" : 24, "hour" : 16 }, "cnt" : 1 },
        { "_id" : { "year" : 2015, "month" : 12, "day" : 25, "hour" : 15 }, "cnt" : 4 },
        { "_id" : { "year" : 2015, "month" : 12, "day" : 25, "hour" : 17 }, "cnt" : 4 }
    ],
    "Microsoft": [
        { "_id" : { "year" : 2015, "month" : 12, "day" : 25, "hour" : 11 }, "cnt" : 1 },
        { "_id" : { "year" : 2015, "month" : 12, "day" : 24, "hour" : 17 }, "cnt" : 1 },
        { "_id" : { "year" : 2015, "month" : 12, "day" : 21, "hour" : 18 }, "cnt" : 2 }
    ]
}
```

[image]

so you can access your data by doing: `result.Google` or `result.Microsoft`

Comment: Thanks for help, the hashtags is an array , can it work?

Comment: hashtags is an array with only one string inside ? 
Please vote if it helped you.

Comment: hashtag is an array but it has one or more string inside, such as ['Microsoft','surface'.....]